# Cannot source vault secrets using the built-in method in gilab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, hashicorp-vault

I can use the JWT auth method and obtain a token:

```
export VAULT_TOKEN=\
$(vault write -field=token auth/jwt/login role=$my_role_name jwt=$CI_JOB_JWT)
```

I can also source variables with `vault kv get` after preforming the above. However, I can't use gitlab's builtin method as described here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/index.html#use-vault-secrets-in-a-ci-job

```
test:
  stage: validate
  secrets:
    TESTSECRET:
      vault: gitlab-ci/TEST_SEC/value@$SECRET_MOUNT
  script:
    - echo $TESTSECRET
```

No errors returned, but the secret does not get sourced.

In CI variables I have:

```
  VAULT_SERVER_URL: "http://myvaultserver.myvaultdomain.net:8200"
  VAULT_AUTH_ROLE: "my_role_name"
```

I'm not sure whether gitlab-ci requires any more config in order to make this builtin method work, as the vault CLI method (within the CI job), works with no issues.

Comment: You may need to file an issue for this if you are confident the setup and configuration is correct.

Comment: possibly. their docs are a bit sketchy on the builtin method and somehow they add "/data" to every vault path, even though the initial setup mentions no "/data" string the path.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the secret mount name directly in the vault keyword instead of reading it from the variable `$SECRET_MOUNT`?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."